# No background for scroll part of page

Tags: html, css

My basic layout for my page is:

```
<body>
<div id="headWrap"></div>
<div id="contentWrap"></div>
</body>
```

headWrap has all my menu items and search bar.  contentWrap holds the content of each page.  Both have a width of 100%.  headWrap uses a repeating background images contentWrap uses a background image much larger than the screen size.

Somehow, when the page is rendered, the horizontal scroll bar is visible.  Even though it appears that all content is on the page.  If I scroll to the side, the background image does not continue, and the scrolled part of the screen is white.  If I stretch the window wide enough the background image takes up the entire page.

How can I find out what is causing the horizontal scroll bar, and why does the background show up when I stretch the window, but not when I scroll.

```
#headWrap{
    position:relative;
    width:auto; 
    height:100px; 
    margin:0px; 
    padding:0px;
    z-index:500; 
    background:url(images/VenueMenu.jpg) repeat-x;
}
#contentWrap{
    position:absolute; 
    top:50px; left:0px;
    text-align:left; 
    z-index:10; 
    width:auto; 
    height:1005; 
    margin:0 0 0 0; 
    padding:0 0 0; 
    float:left; 
    background:url(images/contentBg.jpg) repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: do you have some css? You can use google chrome's inspect element to see what is causing the horizontal stretch .

Comment: @downvoter: What is wrong with this question? If you feel it could be improved try improving it yourself or at least letting someone know why!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following CSS styles: `width`  and  `overflow:hidden;`

```
    html{
        margin: 3px 1px;
    }
    *+html{
        overflow:auto;
    }
    body{
        margin:0;
        width:100%;
        min-width:800px;
        position:relative;
    }

   #headWrap{
    position:relative;
    width:100%; 
    height:100px; 
    margin:0px; 
    padding:0px;
    z-index:500; 
    background:url(images/VenueMenu.jpg) repeat-x;
} 

#contentWrap{
    position:absolute; 
    top:50px; left:0px;
    text-align:left; 
    z-index:10; 
    width:100%; 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    float: left;
    background:url(images/contentBg.jpg) repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: The only problem is that now if I make the window small enough that it should scroll, and scroll, I still get a blank background.

Comment: its hard to say without seeing the example. Does it happen if you manually resize your window, or when you reload in a small window ?

Comment: If I manually re-size the window the page looks fine.  If I re-size then scroll, it's all messed up.

Comment: change your background parameters:  "no-repeat" to "repeat-x"

Comment: made that change, still same problem.  Uploading to server now, should be available.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have some default margins that are added in addition to the 100% width? I suggest using a reset css, for instance [YUI 2: Reset CSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/).

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to set the [overflow CSS property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow).

Comment: my problem is more that the background doesn't display when scrolled, not that the scroll bar is shown

Comment: I apologize for not fully understanding your question. Instead of setting the background of that active div, perhaps create a wrapper div and set that background. Then set the scroller div background to transparent. That way, there shouldn't be any flickering.